# 'clientname' object has no attribute 'set_password'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working with django rest framework, registration and login. and i received this error **'clientname' object has no attribute 'set_password'** how do i solve this problem?

this is my serializers.py

```
class clientnameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = clientname
        fields = ('id','username','password', 'password2' , 'email')
        ordering = ['id',]
        extra_kwargs = {
          'password': {'write_only': True}
        }
    def save(self):
      account = clientname(
        email=self.validated_data['email'],
        username=self.validated_data['username'],
      )
      password = self.validated_data['password']
      password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
      
      if password != password2:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
      account.set_password(password)
      account.save()
      return account
```

this is my views.py

```
@api_view(['POST',])
def registration_view(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = clientnameSerializer(data=request.data)
    data={}
    if serializer.is_valid():
      account = serializer.save()
      data['response'] = "successfully registered a new user."
      data['email'] = account.email
      data['username'] = account.username
    else:
      data = serializer.errors
    return Response(data)
```

this is my full traceback

Traceback:

```
File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner

  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  505.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  465.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  476.         raise exc

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  502.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py" in handler
  50.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/Homepage/api/views.py" in registration_view
  25.       account = serializer.save()

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/Homepage/api/serializers.py" in save
  30.       account.set_password(password)
```

this is my **clientname** model

```
class clientname(models.Model):

  username = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True,blank=True)
  password = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True,blank=True)
  email = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: share you ```clientname``` model.

Comment: @mursalin done..

Answer (score 0):

`set_password()` is a method from Django `User` Model. see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/), if you want to use a custom user you have to create a custom user model extending Django's user model.

note: [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) might help you if you are looking for custom user model